# Web Application: Preprocess and send all items in one page load, or separate the items into separate client requests?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, performance, optimization

I have been tasked with supervising the rewrite/modernization of our firm's ancient (1990s!) PHP application. Of course, I approach this task with both excitement and trepidation. I have spent weeks researching frameworks, libraries, benchmarks and the like.

One of the main functions of this system is to load data items from the backend MySQL db and present them to frontend users. Which items display is a complex issue, but it could any combination or number of items. Say, for example, like a catalog. A user might view one item, browse categories of items, or search for items. Additionally, there are many restrictions and conditions on visibility, and other specific item level data.

My specific question is:

**What are the experts' thoughts on loading and displaying the item data? In terms of page load times, server strain, or any other factor... Should I 
(A): have the server compute all of the output data and then send it to the client (browser) in the initial page request?

(B): Or, should I output a basic page skeleton along with a list of IDs in a javascript variable, and then have the client request each item separately and then have a responder send back the (JSON?) data and have the client populate pages?**

What I am seeking here is some programmers' wisdom, on what has worked best. I don't want advice that tells me to switch from PHP to another language, or that I need to run my own tests. I am not asking anyone to write any code for me. I simply want your wisdom / advice on which way would be better and why, or factors would make a case for one approach vs the other.

While scenario (A) seems old school to me, and less flexible. I think it may be faster for the frontend users. If my server as max-optimized and cached-out, shouldn't this (still) be the most efficient way?

Option (B) seems cooler and more 'modern' but is there any point to this approach? What would I gain, except for perhaps some front-end JavaScript and dynamic templating skills? It seems that each page load could require dozens of additional requests, as well as extra client side processing, which to me is against the latest page speed optimization advice from the big guns.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the way you have worded options A and B. The clear choice is A. Here's why:

> ...along with a list of IDs in a javascript variable, **and then have the client request each item separately** and then have...

That is going to result in very poor performance as now you are doing many `SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=x` that each return 1 record, instead of `SELECT * FROM items WHERE something_else` so no you have the over head of each of those MySQL queries, plus each HTTP request, bad efficiency.

So, as you have it worded, option A for sure.

But, lets go back to the gist of what I think you are getting at with option B...

Let's say you have an HTML/web search interface, all of that is served on the first request, with no results. Now I enter the search parameters, and hit "go". In the background (js/ajax), my criteria can be sent to the server and processed, and you send a back a JSON object of the first page of items (only the data, item_name, item_id, item_desc, etc, no html, no styles) then the browser draws it to the page using javascript.

Why this might be better? You can now think of your backend/server-side as an API, taking queries and returning data, which is pretty clean code-design wise. It doesn't have to loop through things adding HTML, no image assets, etc. This is very flexible because now lets say you get the order to make this item system accessible via an iPhone app! Problem? Not really, you already have a JSON API, so your iPhone app can hit this API the same way, and present the data inside the app appropriately.

Back to web-browser side: This is also probably going to result in a faster user experience, since the data you are sending back is 1) easier/faster for the server to render 2) a smaller amount of data since it is ONLY the item data, and not its HTML formatting, or the surrounding page elements.

I hope this helps provide some more insight into your decision. Good luck!

Comment: I see your point. Thanks, I will contemplate your advice, ultimately this type of flexibility seems worth it.